# Error: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry , when import project from eclips to android studio

Tags: android

my manifast add this library

```
 <uses-sdk tools:overrideLibrary="android.support.multidex,android.support.v7.appcompat,android.support.graphics.drawable,android.support.v4"/>
```

I'm trying to add a library to my project, right now my current build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'android'
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.+"
compile project(':appcompat_v7')
}

android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
defaultConfig {

 multiDexEnabled true
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    instrumentTest.setRoot('tests')

    debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')

    release.setRoot('build-types/release')
}
}
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':mot:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/accessibilityservice/AccessibilityServiceInfoCompat$AccessibilityServiceInfoIcsImpl.class